# Jquery autocomplete results stuck

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to use JQuery autocomplete on some forms. Everything works fine, except the results box. It seems to be "stuck".

Let's say I have "username" "John123" in my database. When I type "jo" in the field, I get the correct result. But when I continue and type "johx", "John123" keeps showing as suggestion.

I have tried different forms, databases, JQuery versions, but still the same issue.

[image: Sad:(]

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('keydown', '.search', function() {
    
    var id = this.id;
    var splitid = id.split('_');
    var index = splitid[1];

    $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "readC.php",
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    search: request.term,request:1
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

            // AJAX
            $.ajax({
                url: 'readC.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {userid:userid,request:2},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){
                    
                    var len = response.length;

                    if(len > 0){
                        var id = response[0]['id'];
                        var last_name = response[0]['last_name'];
                        var first_name = response[0]['first_name'];
                        var company = response[0]['company'];
                        var id_code = response[0]['id_code'];

                        document.getElementById('last_name').value = last_name;
                        document.getElementById('first_name').value = first_name;
                        document.getElementById('company').value = company;
                        document.getElementById('id_code').value = id_code;
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
});
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in case other people experience same issues in the future.

The problem only appeared when using Xampp on a local server.

So I assume it's something to do with Xampp, but difficult to pinpoint exactly.